# upload files using a number associated with each file instead of the name of the file

Tags: python

Im showing the list of current files in a directory.

And for each file Im showing a number associated, and then I want to ask user to digit 3 file, but not with file name, I want using the associated number.

So Im storing each filename with number associated in a dictonary.

And now Im trying to upload using the number associated to each file, but Im not having sucess doing this.

Someone already did something like this and can give me a help?

```
import os 

def upload(file_name_number): 

    filename = raw_input(file_name_number)

    if(os.path.exists(filename)):
        key.set_contents_from_filename(filename)
    else:
        print "The selected number does not exist in current directory."
        upload(file_name_number)
    return filename    

def create():

    showListAndSaveDict()

    firstFile  = upload("Select the number of first file:")
    secondFile = upload("Select the number of second file:")
    thirdFile  = upload("Select the number of third file:") 

def showListAndSaveDict():
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    files_dict = {}
    i=0
    for f in files:
        i = i+1
        print (str(i) + " - " + f)  
        files_dict[i] = f
    return files_dict

create()
```

Comment: what is the relation between number and file?

Comment: Im showing all the filenames associated with a number, and Im asking user to write the number that appears next to the filename. So there isnt a relation between number and file. But Im trying to create that relation, What I thought was, save a dictonary with key (number that appears next to the filename) and value (the filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a dictionary for mapping number to file name but in the upload function you are checking whether file with number exists or not which will be false as files are stored with names and not numbers.You need to check whether that number exists in dict or not.

```
import os

def upload(file_name_number,files_dict): 

    filename = int(raw_input(file_name_number))
    #as the key to dictionary is integer
    if filename in files_dict:
        # upload code here
        print "dummy"
    else:
        print "The selected number does not exist in current directory."
        upload(file_name_number,files_dict)#why are you calling this again
    return filename

def create():
    files_dict = showListAndSaveDict()
    firstFile  = upload("Select the number of first file:",files_dict)
    secondFile = upload("Select the number of second file:",files_dict)
    thirdFile  = upload("Select the number of third file:",files_dict)

def showListAndSaveDict():
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    files_dict = {}
    i=0
    for f in files:
        i = i+1
        print (str(i) + " - " + f)  
        files_dict[i] = f
    return files_dict

create()
```

Comment: don't use .keys just use  `in files_dict`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I have upload(file_name_number) after show the message "The selected number does not exist in current directory" to ask again user to write the file number if we writes a number that does not exist.   And Im trying to do as you said, but when I use the dictonary when I call upload() method I get always error that files_dict is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, but with your solution in upload("Select the number....") lines Im always getting this: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: Here:  firstFile  = upload("Select the number of first file:",files_dict)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74287/discussion-between-avinash-pandey-and-userx).

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything in `create()` and you don't pass a dict therefore you won't be able to access it so you may be better off moving the logic to `upload` and forget the other functions using a  while loop to keep looping until three files are uploaded

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

def upload():
    file_dict = showListAndSaveDict()
    # kepp track of how many successful uploads
    uploaded = 0
    # keep list of all files uploaded
    files_uploaded = []
    # keep looping until three files have been successfully uploaded
    while uploaded < 3:
        for k,v in file_dict.iteritems():
            print("Number {}: file: {}".format(k,v))
        file_number = raw_input("Please choose a file number")
        # make sure choice is valid
        if file_number in file_dict:
            # do whatever
            # increase count 
            uploaded += 1
            files_uploaded.append(file_dict[file_number])
        else:
            # key was not in dict
            print "The selected number does not exist in current directory."
    return files_uploaded


def showListAndSaveDict():
    files = (f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f))
    return {str(k):"{}-{}".format(k,f)  for k, f in enumerate(files)}
```

I presume there is supposed to be another function that actually uploads the files which should be call in place of # do whatever

You should always use a while loop instead of the function repeatedly calling itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with your solution Im always getting "The selected number does not exist in current directory". Im here trying to find where the issue is!

Comment: sorry, missed a str call, should be fixed

Comment: Thank you, it was really that the issue!  But now Im getting other error if I select the number 1 that corresponds to filename_test.py: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1-filename_test.py'

Comment: that is because you wanted to add  `1-` etc..  `filename_test.py` is the name not `1-filename_test.py`, I will edit in a minute

Comment: @UserX, had to change your logic